# Three.js GPGPUComputationRenderer and OES_texture_float

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, gpgpu, fbo

I am using the GPGPUComputationRenderer.js to handle alot of particles with interactivity on the GPU. But it looks like it requires the OES_texture_float extension by default. I need to support some devices that doesn't have this extension.

I have based much of my code on the GPGPUComputationRenderer, and specifically this example: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_gpgpu_birds

Is it possible that someone can help me in the right direction of how to get this example working without the need of the floating point extension (less precision)? Is it possible at all, or should I take another approach?

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: what specifically are your particles doing? what are they being used for?

Comment: I have a sea of particles (4 planes with some animated noise), mouse interactivity and some FBX models I load up that should also have some interactivity. I figured FBO was a good approach, since I can have a velocity map texture to read from. The FBX models are also using the THREE.Points class.